# Identifying a terminal from the opened terminal tabs

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using multiple terminals tabs. Through ssh I'm connecting to different ip addresses, but all having the same username and host name. So I'm unable to identify the required terminal easily

```
ssh namex@ipadress1
ssh namex@ipaddress2
```

so all opened tabs have the same title.

Is there a way to differentiate these tabs.

Comment: Some consoles have options to change tab's color (I am using iterm2) that could be helpful in recognition. But you can check if there is such of option for yours as well. Which one you use?

Comment: I'm using the default terminal for Ubunut 16.04, gnome terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing hostname temporarily.
`sudo hostname NEW_NAME_HERE`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in each tab, type what title you want, and be disorganized no more!

`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033]0;YOUR-TEXT-HERE\a"'`

---

GUI Method: 
If you're using the Terminal application on Mac OSX, if you simply double click on a tab, a Inspector pop-window will appear and you can edit a Tab Title from there.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04